# ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de seleccionar una columna en un dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

espero que estén bien.

Estoy comenzando a aprender a usar **Pandas** para manipular Dataframes. Tengo la duda de cual es la mejor manera para seleccionar una columna. Las dos maneras que conozco son:

```
dataframe['columna']

dataframe.columna
```

A mi personalmente me gusta más usar la segunda porque cuando escribo el punto automáticamente me da opción para elegir entre los nombres de las columnas, en cambio con las comillas simples no.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: La segunda es más comoda como tu dices, pero ten en cuenta que a veces hay situaciones en las que no te valdría y tendrías que optar por la primera, por ejemplo si existen espacios en el nombre.

Comment: Otra forma de seleccionar una columna. poco convencional podría ser `dataframe[dataframe.columns[0]]` de esa manera mostrarías la columna 0, o sea la primer columna. A veces puede pasar que las columnas no tengan nombre(aunque se pueden "renombrar" ). pero una manera de acceder, puede ser esa.  `dataframe.columns` devuelve todas las columnas de un `DataFrame`

Comment: Aún hay otra forma, y es por el índice de la columna en vez de por su nombre, por ejemplo, para seleccionar la tercera columna: `dataframe.iloc[:, 2]` (2 es la tercera porque se numeran desde 0)